# How can I stop str_replace replacing only part of a filename?

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I'm going through an HTML file replacing all the references to external files with new ones, however, sometimes this results in errors.

For example:  I want to replace all instances of `styles.css` with `1.css` and all instances of `iestyles.css` with `2.css` in this source code:

```
<html>
  <link href="styles.css" />
  <link href="iestyles.css" />
</html>
```

Once I've run `str_replace("styles.css", "1.css", $html);` the source code looks like this:

```
<html>
  <link href="1.css" />
  <link href="ie1.css" />
</html>
```

So when I run the second query, it doesn't change the `iestyles.css` reference because it no longer exists.  Is there a way around this?  I guess I could invent an elaborate regular expression, but there are a lot of variables to consider because not all code is well formed.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order: First replace `iestyles.css` with `2.css` and then replace `styles.css` with `1.css`.

If you are sure the filename is the only thing within the `href`-attribut, you could also include the double quotes `"`

```
$html = str_replace('"styles.css"', '"1.css"', $html);
$html = str_replace('"iestyles.css"', '"2.css"', $html);
```

Comment: OP could also replace second for `ie1.css` :)

Comment: Thing is, I can't be sure exactly what the filenames will be - this is just an example.  So how do I know which to do first if there is a huge list of references to be replaced?  I also can't be sure if double or single quotes were used or indeed if quotes were used at all.  As I said, not all code is well-formed.

Comment: "no quotes" is not only "not well-formed", but its broken. That as a side note ;) However, like @cwallenpoole suggests its always useful to replace from big to small. Just sort the "from"-strings by their length is a good start.

Comment: Hey, you suggested it, I just 1+'d it.

Comment: Yes, it's a good start but it isn't a solution.  I'm talking about quite a large scale.  There could be hundreds of references to replace and the filenames could be anything at all.  I need a sure-fire way of making sure each one is replaced properly.

Comment: Why it isn't a solution? As far as I can see the replacement is always numerical and the search-strings is not-numeric, so there is absolutely no situation, where you may accidentally double-replace entries. Just get the search-strings, order they, then iterate over the ordered search-strings and replace them with the replace-strings.

Comment: It's very possible that the string to replace could be a number.  But yes, you are right and it's a good idea - just not a complete solution for all possibilities.

Comment: As far as I can see you can only cover _all_ possibilities, when you parse the document (e.g. as `DOMDocument`), iterating over the `link`-elements and replacing their `href`-attribute. Because you mentioned, that the documents may be broken, its not said, that this approach would not simply fail. However, in my opinion the `str_replace()` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Including the double quotes (assuming they all use double quotes) should work.

```
str_replace('"styles.css"', '"1.css"', $html);
```

Comment: Yeah, I can't be sure they will always be double quotes though :\

Answer (score 0):

use preg_replace();

```
preg_replace('|<link href="styles\.css" />|', '1.css', $html);
```

or just prepend double quotes before `styles`

```
str_replace('"styles.css', '"1.css', $html);
```

Comment: I can't be sure that the format of the link will be the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the quotes in your replacement.

replace `"styles.css"` with `"1.css"`

Answer (score 0):

You could change 'iestyles.css' first.